# Why does creating a PDF from Word using VBA give a bigger file size than doing it manually?

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I have a Word macro in VBA which does various things to a document and then creates a pdf of it. The trouble is that the pdf it creates is about twice the size of the pdf that I create if I do it manually.

The really bizarre thing is that I recorded a macro while I did it manually to see what the VBA code would be from doing it manually. And then when I run the exact code that I recorded, the file size doubles.

Here is the code that I recorded, which creates a PDF double the size of the one that got created while I recorded it.

```
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    "[filename].pdf", _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=False, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=False, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

Any ideas how I can change the code to give a smaller file size?

I'm using Word 2013, and have Adobe Acrobat Standard DC 2015 installed.

Comment: When you create the PDF manually, are you exporting to PDF using the Word native export or using the Acrobat ribbon (save as Adobe PDF)? Your code uses the native export engine rather than Acrobat which will often produce a much smaller file.

Comment: I'm using the "save as Adobe PDF" option when I do it manually. But oddly, that's what I did when I recorded the code above.

Do you know if there is a way to use Acrobat via VBA?

Comment: You can control the Acrobat application via VBA but I'm not aware of a way to automate PDF creation from Word using the Adobe macro via VBA.